# python 3 redirect to magnet

Tags: python, python-3.x, redirect

I just started python and am trying to interact with the webpages for a project that I am currently working on.

I am trying to retrieve the magnet link that the URL redirects to
But i get HTTP Error 302

```
trial = urllib.request.Request("https://www.shanaproject.com/download/149913/")
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(redirectdefn.SmartRedirectHandler())
f = opener.open(trial)
```

For that reason i re-defined the error in the file redirectdefn given below

```
 import urllib.request

class SmartRedirectHandler(urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        #print(urllib.request.geturl())
        print("Redirected")
```

But it still gives me the error 302.
How do I get the magnet link that it redirects to?

Comment: A 302 is not an error but a redirect. The URL you are looking for is in the `Location` header of the 302 response.

Answer (score 1):

You could just catch the error and extract the URL from the exception:

```
try:
    urllib.request.urlopen(trial)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print("url is", e.url)
```